# The sequence : $\sum_{n\ge2} {\frac{1}{\ln^2 x}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to know if the next sequence converge or diverge. $$\sum_{n\ge 2} {\frac{1}{\ln^2 n}}$$
I have tried the limit comparison test but I did not solve the problem.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's Condensation test?

Comment: Hint: any power of $\ln x$ is less than any positive power of $x$, for $x$ large enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean $$\sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{1}{\ln^2 n},$$ [you can't use $n = 1$ because the summand is undefined when $n = 1$]. The sum is divergent. Asymptotically, any power of $n$ is larger than any power of $\ln(n)$. Hence, for example, there is an $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $n \ge N$ gives $\ln^2(n) \le n$ so that $$\frac 1 n \le \frac{1}{\ln^2(n)}.$$ Thus we see $$\sum_{n \ge N} \frac{1}{n} \le \sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{1}{\ln^2(n)};$$ the latter must diverge since the former does.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

From [Cauchy's Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), we have that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\log^2(n)}$ converges if and only if the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{\log^2(2^n)}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^2\log^2(2)}$$

converges.  Does the general term of the "condensed" series tend to $0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark